Error Encountered an issue when uploading and creating pre-authenticated URLs. process is holding on
We are using OCI Java SDK to integrate Object Storage with our services and facing issues of thread holding.
Each call is holding one thread. For example, if we make a call to a pre-authenticated URL with five files, it holds five threads.
This continuous increase in thread count results in the holding of system-native threads.
Problematic methods :

createPreauthenticatedRequest.getPreauthenticatedRequest();
getObjectStorage().putObject(putObjectRequest);

Any suggestions where I may be going wrong?
Tried the latest SDKs and Java versions but the problem exists.

Which version are you using? There was an issue with the thread leak in versions >= 3.31.0 and <= 3.38.0. See here- https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/issues/587

We were using 3.34 version and now going to try with 3.39.2. Will revert back with the findings
